# How to write handlebars if condition for title text

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to show on pagination buttons `title="text"`, I got to show on the button when I hover the link to page from some pages

But, how can I implement title text to the current Page?

Here is my code:

```
<li class="files-overview__pagination-item{{#is data.root.currentPage hash.pageNr}} is-active{{/is}}">
<a class="files-overview__pagination-link"
   data-js-item="files-overview__pagination-item"
   data-pagination-page="{{hash.pageNr}}"
   title="
   {{data.root.currentPage hash.pageNr}} current page}}
   jump to page {{hash.pageName}} of {{data.root.totalPages}}"
   >
   {{hash.pageName}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

some correction to the Code:

```
<li class="files-overview__pagination-item{{#is data.root.currentPage hash.pageNr}} is-active{{/is}}">
<a class="files-overview__pagination-link"
   data-js-item="files-overview__pagination-item"
   data-pagination-page="{{hash.pageNr}}"
   title="
   {{#if data.root.currentPage hash.pageName}} current page{{else}}
   jump to page {{hash.pageName}} of {{data.root.totalPages}}
   {{/if}}
   "
   >
   {{hash.pageName}}
</a>
```